# Laravel DB::transaction not accepting variables

Tags: php, database, laravel, transactions

Good day, please I have something that I can't catch the error, I am trying to implement DB::transaction() in my project, I have 3 tables I have to insert data, I created my own function to do it before, but I want to refactor my code to use laravel DB::transaction().
I went through the documentation [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions), but I am having an error, the error is that it is not seeing the variables that I am passing inside the function in the transaction

> 'introduction' => $request->introduction,

I am getting **Undefined variable 'request'
Below is my complete function

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'introduction' => 'required|max:255',
            'budget' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $id = Auth::id();

        // $project = Project::create($data);


        DB::transaction(function () {
            $project = Project::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'introduction' => $request->introduction,
                'budget' => $request->budget

            ]);
            DB::table('approvals')->insert(['project_id' => $project->id]);
            DB::table('agreements')->insert(['project_id' => $project->id]);
        });
    }
```

How do I pass the $request->name to the function,
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `use` in your function just like as below:

```
DB::transaction(function () use($request) {
    $project = Project::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'introduction' => $request->introduction,
        'budget' => $request->budget

    ]);
    DB::table('approvals')->insert(['project_id' => $project->id]);
    DB::table('agreements')->insert(['project_id' => $project->id]);
});
```